# Changing the stored value in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

My winform is capable of storing values entered into textbox, then when the appropriate node is selected on a treeview, these values return to the text box that they were entered into. However, I'm having an issue in trying to amend my program so that the user can over write the value they have stored.

This is how its set up at the moment:

```
private void tagTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _screenTag = tagTextBox.Text;

    if (_selectedNode > -1)
    {
        Node n = _nodeList[_nodeList.Count - 1];
        n.Tag = _screenTag;
    }
}
```

The above method first stores the value entered into my tagTextbox. Next I pass this into a dictionary that contains a list of nodes (custom class and not to be confused with a treeview node, sorry):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Entry> pair in n.nodeDictionary)
{             
    if (pair.Key == "Tag ")
    {
        tagTextBox.Text = (string)pair.Value.value;
    }
}
```

The above method gets called when any node (not my class node, a tree node (sorry if thats confusing) ) on my treeview is selected. This brings back the stored value and re-enters it back the proper textbox.

Now, this is my current attempt at trying to change and update the value on the tag textbox that is associated with my screen:

```
private void tagTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    // Update the name when enter is pressed
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (_selectedNode > -1)
        {
            HV_Screen s = _screenList[_screenList.Count - 1];
            s.Tag = _screenTag;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've checked, and this method is getting called but its not updating. I know is normally a simple thing to do, but I'm really confused here and I've spent 8 hours looking at trying to figure out how to fix this issue with no luck.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong / missing?

Comment: If your `textbox` value not get updated then I think you should try `textbox.Update()` or force GUI change.

Comment: tried that, and it doesn't work. Thank you though.

Comment: A) Check the order that events are firing with debugger break points.  B) Check the value that does not seem to be updating in the debugger as well as the displayed value.

Comment: If your textbox is a multiline one, pressing Enter will change the text, and then it might be an issue of event order since `tagTextBox_TextChanged` will be fired as well. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this is trying to achieve

```
if (_selectedNode > -1)
{
    Node n = _nodeList[_nodeList.Count - 1];
    n.Tag = _screenTag;
}
```

shouldn't it be like this:

```
if (_selectedNode > -1)
     _nodeList[_selectedNode].Tag = _screenTag;
```

This maybe it? I'm not sure though, it's hard to see what you're trying to achieve.
The reason is you're not using the _selectedNode at all, just knowing that it more. How do you set your _selectedNode, that may impact. Have I misunderstood?

I would re-write the loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Entry> pair in n.nodeDictionary)
{             
    if (pair.Key == "Tag ")
    {
        tagTextBox.Text = (string)pair.Value.value;
    }
}
```

as:

```
tagTextBox.Text = n.nodeDictionary.Where(x => x.Key.Equals("Tag")).value;
```

it may have to be this (i'm doing it off the top of my head):

```
tagTextBox.Text = n.nodeDictionary.Where(x => x.Key.Equals("Tag")).FirstOrDefault().value;
```

I do it like this, just because to me it's easier to read and manipulate IMHO, but up to you really. Obviouse advantage, I just reduced 7 lines to 1. Secondly, readability hasn't been affected. it reads nicely: Look in nodictionary `=>` where keys `==` tag `=>` get the first one from the list `=>` get its value.